# How to update USING sum and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, nosql-aggregation, subquery

I have a SQL Server table similar to this:

| InkitemNo | CapacityUnit | NewInk | OldInk | ReturnInk | ProdQty | Description | UsedInk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204 | Machine1 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 4000 | Next | ? |
| 223 | machine2 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 8000 | NULL | ? |
| 204 | Machine2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5000 | Next | ? |
| 224 | Machine2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 3000 | Next | ? |

I'm trying to write a query with this formula:

Example to get 1 row used ink

```
(5 + 2 -2 )* 4000/ 12000 = 1,67
```

to get 2 row used ink

```
(4 + 3 - 1) = 6
```

to get 3 row usedink

```
(5 + 2 - 2) * 5000 / 12000 = 2,08
```

to get 4 row usedink

```
(5 + 2 - 2) * 3000 / 12000 = 1,25

(NewInk + OldInk - ReturnInk) * ProdQty / Sum(ProdQty)
```

This formula used when the criteria is

- CapacityUnit & InkItemNo is same
- Description is not NULL

To get the result of used ink, I used this query

```
update InkEstimationSave =
```

(NewInk + OldInk - ReturnInk) * ProdQty / Sum(ProdQty]

but it does not work.

Comment: How does `(5 + 2 -2 )* 4000/ 12000 = 1,67` possible ? AND why always `(NewInk + OldInk - ReturnInk) = (5 + 2 -2 )` ? Your logic and sample data never match

Comment: did you find my answer useful?

Comment: because the criteria and InkItemNo is same so it will calculated on this way(5+2-2) * 4000/12000 = 1,67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your logic query you are looking for is

[fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=440fb492f5540b806b98727c8e3a2714)

```
    ;with cte as 
(
select *, SUM(ProdQty) OVER (partition by InkItemNo, Capacityunit) as denom 
from yourtable
)

update  cte
set UsedInk =
           (newInk+OldInk - ReturnInk) * ProdQty
          /denom
         *1.00 
where Description is NOT NULL

select * from Yourtable
```

Comment: sir when i try your query in my data table  i think this way not work so far like this.
and also thank you to help me i get a references from your query

Comment: sir i think it need to make sum(newInk+OldInk-ReturnInk) as NOR 
then used ink = NOR* ProdQty/Denom *1.000
but how to write this query ?

Comment: @VincentGoh can you add data to fiddle and share the link again after adding data

Comment: sir i already import the data from sql server to excel , but how i  can add the data to fiddle ?

Comment: modify the insert data statements

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb9963bcc20bd8be7fee8829e9745f13
the formula is  pemakaianperpoduksi =  sum(TintaBaru+TintaBekas-Kembali ) * Production Quantity / Sum(Production Quantity)

Comment: thank you sir after see your query i get the way to solved it

Comment: @VincentGoh i'd appreciate if you vote the answer